# Optimaze Regex method (split alphanumeric words from a text line)

Tags: c#, regex

I have issues with performance when using Regex.
The methods I'm using is works as expected, but it takes long time to handle large text files.

I need to take from each line of the file only words:
"tjdj47***ss__s*47 djj ___ s_sd4 4"

Should return list of words (any alpha or alphanumeric sequence that has more then 1 character)

```
tjdj47
ss
47
djj
sd4
```

I use Regex pattern

```
 pattern = new Regex(
            @"([A-Za-z0-9]
            ([A-Za-z0-9])*
            [A-Za-z0-9])",
            RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Method that filters and splits words

```
public List<string> SplitLineIntoWords(string lineText)
    {
        List<string> lineWords = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match m in pattern.Matches(lineText))
        {
            lineWords.Add(m.Groups[1].Value.ToLower());
        }

        return lineWords;
    }
```

How can I optimize method to execute faster? (Now, it takes up to 25 seconds to separate words from a file with size 350mb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression basically matches substrings that contain at least 2 alphanumeric chars.

Use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5BA-Za-z0-9%5D%7B2%2C%7D&i=tjdj47***ss__s*47%20djj%20___%20s_sd4%204).

See a benchmark at RegexHero.net:

[image]

The `([A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9])*[A-Za-z0-9])` requires a lot more time to match because of the backtracking (and also  filling up the second group stack):

- The `[A-Za-z0-9]` matches an alphanumeric, then
- `([A-Za-z0-9])*` matches and captures each alphanumeric, as many as possible
- `[A-Za-z0-9]` requires a char to match, thus, the engine steps back, and lets an alphanumeric char to be matched with this last subpatter.

With `[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}` there is no backtracking since there is only one way to match a string with it.

Here is a comparison of how the two patterns get only the first match (done with PCRE option, but it is very close to what .NET does): 1) [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/R2kTWY/1/debugger) and 2) [my solution](https://regex101.com/r/iUuv9f/1/debugger).

***Regex 1***:

[image]

***Regex 2***:

[image]

Comment: foreach is faster for 1-2 seconds then casting, selecting and converting to list. But, it still takes 18 seconds even after changing the pattern. Can I do something to improve performance more?

Comment: @MrgGek: There is no way to improve the performance by modifying the regex pattern. It is quite optimized. No idea if `[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]+` is any better.

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]+` seems to be a little fast no matter what configuration: `00:00:122.2704436` vs `00:00:122.6907316`

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the regex to `"[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}"` which match the character group at least 2times or more.

Comment: Thank you, after I changed the pattern performance increased from 25 to 18 seconds. But, still it's long... Can I do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose main reason why you can encounter this problem is **backtracking**. Change your regex to this:

```
@"[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}".
```

As for your regex, this part:

```
([A-Za-z0-9])*
```

Will backtrack on every word one time, so you basically scanning every word **two times**. The first one mathes `[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9])*` then fails on `[A-Za-z0-9]` and backtrack to first `[A-Za-z0-9]`, then scanning whole example and matches it.